# SumatraPDF with AucTeX and Foxit Reader as the default viewer

Tags: emacs, auctex, viewers

I like to use Foxit Reader to view PDF's but it locks the file so i cannot use synctex with it.
So I'd like to use SumatraPDF with AuCTeX when making my PDF's but still have Foxit Reader as my default pdf viewer.
I use windows XP, AuCTeX 11.86 and GNU Emacs 23.3.

Answer (score 3):

After son hours of struggle i finally got what i want.
First you set the PDF viewer of your preference, then you follows these steps
http://blog.modelworks.ch/?p=210 (note that you have to set the program list first, then restart emacs, then set the program view selection and restart emacs again) and you are done.

In my case i had to change `<directory of your SumatraPDF.exe> -reuse-instance %o` to `start SumatraPDF -reuse-instance %o` but i don't know the reason, maybe you can explain this to me.

Comment: Great that you got it. It surely is difficult to customize Emacs and AucTeX

Answer (score 0):

No problem. Just use the howto here: http://william.famille-blum.org/blog/static.php?page=static081010-000413 for emacs.

SumatraPDF will become the standard viewer for AucTeX, but not for Windows!

Comment: I already set up SyncTeX with SumatraPDF but now it seems that the problem is that i can't properly add "sumatraPDF" To the TeX-view-program-list and then choose it at the TeX-view-program-selection. I followed these instructions: http://hoxide.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/auctex-sumatra-pdf/ but then the command TeX-view does not work.

Comment: @Keks Dose wrote:"SumatraPDF will become the standard viewer for AucTeX, but not for Windows!" That makes no sense. SumatraPDF is Windows only browser! On *nix one needs to use MuPDF or write a new PDF viewer in order to use the same PDF rendering libraries like SumatraPDF.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac It makes sense. If you customise Emacs/AUCTeX on a Windows-PC, you may make SumatraPDF to be the default PDF viewer for all PDFs started using Emacs commands. But this does not influence at all the behaviour of other software, e.g. the explorer.

Comment: Link is dead. That's why good answers [provide context for links](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @feklee 1. Link is not dead. 2. Thank you for downvoting me and giving smart comments.

Comment: It was dead when I posted my comment. Anyhow, a good answer provides context, not just a link. No need for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a batch file, `Emacs_SumatraPDF.bat`.

It works perfect with `sumatra-forward.el` to realize forward and backward search.

### For example:

**Download**

http://www.ai.soc.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~shi/files/Emacs_SumatraPDF.bat

http://william.famille-blum.org/software/sumatra/sumatra-forward.el

---

**Prepare**

put `Emacs_SumatraPDF.bat` and `SumatraPDF.exe` --> 
     `%Emacs_Home%/bin`.

put `sumatra-forward.el` --> `%Emacs_Home%/site-lisp`

---

**Usage**

```
;Emacs_Home=C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Emacs 23.4
;~\.emacs add following information


;;; Emacs_SumatraPDF.bat
;;  @info: pdf viewer 
;   @refer: 
(setq TeX-view-program-list '(
      ("Sumatra" "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Emacs 23.4/bin/Emacs_SumatraPDF.bat 
                   %o %t %n") ))         

(setq TeX-view-program-selection '(
     (output-pdf "Sumatra") 
     (output-dvi "Yap") 
     ((output-dvi style-pstricks) "dvips and start") 
     (output-html "start"))) 

 ;;; sumatra-forward.el
 ;;  @info: forward search. 
 ;   @refer: http:/william.famille-blum.org/blog/static.php?page=static081010-000413
 (require 'sumatra-forward)
```

That is all.

---

**Besides**

**Emacs 4 Latex Support** under Windows 7 for newcomer for Emacs.

http://www.ai.soc.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~shi/latex/emacs4ls.html

---

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 0):

What works for me with `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2013-03-17
on MARVIN` on Windows XP (German):

```
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("Sumatra PDF"
         "C:/Programme/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe -reuse-instance %o")))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection
      '(((output-dvi style-pstricks) "dvips and start")
        (output-dvi "Yap")
        (output-pdf "Sumatra PDF")
        (output-html "start")))
```